# How we can trigger jenkins job which takes source code from one repository, whenever a developer push changes to their beanstalk-git repository?

Tags: jenkins, github, automation, webhooks, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run(trigger) my jenkins job whenever a push happens to developer repository.

Firstly,

1. i'm storing all my automation scripts in my personal GitHub.
2. All of my developer's code is another GitHub, i.e in beanstalk which is top of GitHub

Now whenever dev's pushes their changes to their repository, then i want trigger my jenkins job which takes source code from my personal GitHub.

So, after some research on it, i came to know **Webhooks** will help in this.

Bu in my case as per their are two separate repositories, i couldn't able to get what exactly i have to do.

Any solution appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution, I can think of is you can build a WebHook and Git integration on your Dev's repository to trigger your Jenkins job, and in the build steps you can perform the check-out of your git repository source code using git commands.

Comment: Steps with details or Images or reference to detailed tutorials may be helpful here.

Comment: For webhook: [link](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline), For git commands: [link](https://github.com/joshnh/Git-Commands)